# Trying to add Data from Excel to Java

Tags: java

Basically the data in  is in a table that has

3 columons, student name, weight, and age. 
3 Rows, that have all the info.
(this is just test data there can be unlimited number of rows)

How would I would seperate the values in each of the columons in java?

cant use Apache POI for this.

Comment: when you say table means db or excel?

Comment: Yes if you are reading or writing to excel/csv POI is the best way

Comment: Well you have to look at the Apache poi source.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to store the data, then you can store the name(String), weight(double), and age(int), all in a String type array, in the form
    `String[] data1 = new String[3];`
since there is 3 items in the array. To store each piece of data, 
    `data1[0] = "a";`
    `data1[1] = "b";`
    `data1[2] = "c";`
is used and then if you wanted to call the name of the student (or whichever you choose to store in the first column), you could refer to the 0th entry for each array (data1, data2, data3... datan). Similarly, if you wanted to put all the data in one single array, you could use a two dimensional array in the form
    `String[][] data = new String[3][3]`
.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the data from Excel as a CSV list
2. Create a model (=class) for your data which represents all columns with it's fields
3. Import using either a library to read CSV lists or write one on your own with `split`

Each line will be a new object of your model class. Each column will be a field of that class.